# how to get resultsets from sybase stored procedure

Tags: database, t-sql, stored-procedures, sybase, sap-ase

I have a stored procedure with the following format :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_test
    @variable1 int
AS
    SELECT column1, column2, ....
    FROM table_test
```

Because this procedure doesn't return any values explicitly, it's difficult to know how many lines of results have been returned. What's more, I cannot modify this stored procedure since it's created by another programmer and already used in the application.

So my question is, if I want to get the resultset generated by the **select** statement, how can I do it ?

Comment: How are you running the procedure? Interactively through isql or through a script? The syntax appears correct.  Also, why can't you create your own version of the stored procedure to do what you need, or run the same query outside of the stored procedure.

Comment: In fact, I am calling this procedure within my own procedure. I want to count the number of records for the returned result, and then do some logics in my own procedure.

Comment: Since you can't change what is returned in the original SP, why not just put the query logic in your SP, instead of calling the original SP from your new SP?

Comment: @MichaelGardner I've just updated my post. In fact, this existed SP has one parameter, and generate one resultset. If in include this query logic inside my SP, it cannot be called like a function. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After fired the procedure you can try use a session variable  `@@rowcount`:

```
select @@rowcount
```

I'm not sure, maybe it will help you.

Comment: Yep, I was always thinking about retrieve the resulset and do the counting myself. It's really convenient to find what I want already existed in this "great" global variable ! Thank you very much :D